# Copy text to clipboard on RGSS (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, winapi, character-encoding

I'm trying to copy text to the clipboard from a game in RPG Maker VXACE that uses RGSS (Ruby Game Scripting System). The problem is that you are really limited on what you can do there, the ruby version is old and can't use gems or import libraries.

But you can use Win32API. Though I'm not really that familiar with it and complex operations. I was trying to use ChatGPT for a solution, and it came pretty close to working, it managed to copy text to memory but it was garbled, probably due to an encoding issue, or bad file reading (more on that later)

Here is the code that (partially) worked

```rb
OpenClipboard = Win32API.new('user32', 'OpenClipboard', 'L', 'L')
EmptyClipboard = Win32API.new('user32', 'EmptyClipboard', 'V', 'V')
CloseClipboard = Win32API.new('user32', 'CloseClipboard', 'V', 'V')
SetClipboardData = Win32API.new('user32', 'SetClipboardData', 'LL', 'L')
GlobalAlloc = Win32API.new('kernel32', 'GlobalAlloc', 'LL', 'L')
GlobalLock = Win32API.new('kernel32', 'GlobalLock', 'L', 'P')
GlobalUnlock = Win32API.new('kernel32', 'GlobalUnlock', 'L', 'L')
RtlMoveMemory = Win32API.new('kernel32', 'RtlMoveMemory', 'LPL', 'V')
CloseHandle = Win32API.new('kernel32', 'CloseHandle', 'L', 'L')
CreateFile = Win32API.new('kernel32', 'CreateFile', 'PILLPILL', 'L')

def copy_to_clipboard(text)
  game_directory = Dir.pwd  # Get the current working directory (game directory)

  temp_file = File.join(game_directory, 'clipboard_temp.txt')

  # Write the text content to the temporary file
  File.open(temp_file, 'w') do |file|
    file.write(text)
  end

  # Open the temporary file
  file_handle = CreateFile.call(temp_file, 0x80000000, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0)

  # Get the size of the file
  file_size = File.size(temp_file)

  # Allocate memory for the text
  buffer = GlobalAlloc.call(0x2000, file_size + 1)
  ptr = GlobalLock.call(buffer)

  # Read the file content and copy it to the allocated memory
  File.open(temp_file, 'rb') do |file|
    file.read(file_size, ptr)
  end

  # Unlock the memory
  GlobalUnlock.call(buffer)

  # Open the clipboard
  OpenClipboard.call(0)

  # Clear the clipboard
  EmptyClipboard.call

  # Set the clipboard data
  SetClipboardData.call(1, buffer)

  # Close the clipboard
  CloseClipboard.call

  # Close and delete the temporary file
  CloseHandle.call(file_handle)
  File.delete(temp_file)
end

text = "Hello, world!"
copy_to_clipboard(text)
```

This is creating a temporary file and then reading it so we can get the ptr, as a direct conversion seems to not be possible in RGSS.
The problem with this is that the text copied to the clipboard was: "Ð?ÝP»Ô"

ChatGPR deduced that it was an encoding issue and tried to fix it by changing the encoding on file open to utf-8, but it still failed

```rb
File.open(temp_file, 'rb:utf-8') do |file|
```

Next response from ChatGPT was:
In this updated code, we write the text content to the temporary file in binary mode ('wb') and encode it as UTF-16LE (text.encode('UTF-16LE')). We then read the file content in binary mode ('rb') and copy it to the allocated memory.
Additionally, we use 13 as the parameter value for SetClipboardData.call, which corresponds to CF_UNICODETEXT format for text data in the clipboard.

The modified code was:

```rb
File.open(temp_file, 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(text.encode('UTF-16LE'))
  end
```

```rb
buffer = GlobalAlloc.call(0x2000, file_size + 2)
```

```rb
SetClipboardData.call(13, buffer)
```

But it still failed, the text copied now was: "Ӕ䂈ӕؽ⬊ĆĄ妄Њ㄁〭〯"

I think the solution is real close, but I don't know enough about files to get why.

Comment: Run an experiment with simpler inputs. For example, input the text "0", then the text "1", "2", etc. Single, consecutive characters. If the outputs look similar (in binary) then you know you're at least close and it's just an encoding problem. If those outputs look wildly different, you may be reading junk data in memory.

Comment: Also, this AI-written code sucks. Half of it could be replaced with just `ptr.replace(...)` assuming that the Win32 calls are right.